# time.h works in C++ not in C

Tags: c++, c, time, malloc

The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
int main()
{
    time_t start, end;
    time (&start);
    int i;
    double dif;
    /*int serie[100000];*/
    /* int *serie = malloc( sizeof(int) );

    for (i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
        *serie(i)=rand();
        printf("%d \n", serie[i]);
    }
    */
    time (&end);
    dif = difftime (end, start);

    printf ("Time of execution is: %f\n", dif );

    getchar();

    return 0;

}
```

The Introduction: (no need to read it)

I knew a bit of C++ from about 3 years ago. I have decided
to learn C to create a "fast" subset sum algorithm.  This was a
simple program to learn C.  The problem is to create random numbers and
time it.  This code actually works when I compiled as default or
C++ with Visual Studio, but I decided to do it in C
and I wanted to create a dynamic array.

It seems that there is no `new` in C.  We have to use `malloc`,
but to compile `malloc` I think it has to be compiled in C.  In C++,
it gives me this error:

```
cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int *'
```

Anyway, it happens that I decided to write in C, so it seems logical to
compile in C.  I have chosen the `time` function to measure the program,
I like it more than `clock` because I do not know how many processors
are working.

The question:

The code as it is above with the comments compiles perfectly in C++, but in C it doesn't compile.
Specifically, this line:

```
time (&start);
```

gives me this error:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

I just want to compute the start time and the end time and then
subtract them with `difftime` as I have successfully done in C++.

Comment: use `#include <xxx.h>` instead of `#include "xxx.h"`

Comment: `stdafx.h` is unnecessary; it's Microsoft-specific, and you're not using it.  You can call `malloc()` from C++, but the conversion rules are different; it returns a `void*` result, which can be implicitly converted to the target type in C but not in C++.  But you should use `new` and `delete` in C++ anyway -- or better yet, some container class.  And yes, *of course* if you're writing C code you should use a C compiler, and if you're writing C++ code you should use a C++ compiler.  They're different (but closely related) languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet that your C compiler is defaulting to the rule that variable declarations must be at the beginning of a block.

You have your call to `time(&start)` before `int i`. This is OK in C++ but not in C. To be specific, all variables must be declared before any program code in all versions of C until C99. In the 1999 C Standard, the rule changed to be like C++ and you can mix code and variable declarations.

If you have a C99 compiler or a compiler option that does allow C99 rules, still don't do it, because it isn't reliably portable. And even in C99 there are not many good reasons to mix variables and code anyway. The only one I can think of is a C99 variable length array that requires code to calculate the desired length.

Comment: To clarify: variables must be declared at the beginning of the block in C89, while in the new C standard (C99) this restriction is removed.

Comment: I find it quite odd that a 12 year old standard is considered new, and not yet fully adopted.  Whereas in C++, I was eager to move to C++0x *before* it was officially standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It would have taken me a lot of time probably to notice that since the language I know most is php and the syntax is less restrictive. Although I still do not know C I can feel its power and that kind of things syntax... makes you in the end write better code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: It all depends. Once in a while you find yourself trying to port code to an embedded system whose last supported compiler was released in 2003, which was built from a base released in 2000.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I'd love to move to C++0x but I have people who still want us to build libraries for Fedora 4 and Redhat Enterprise 2AS.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, it is odd.  There aren't many compilers that *fully* implement C99.  Microsoft's compiler, in particular, has reasonably good C90 conformance (if you invoke it properly), but supports very few C99-specific features.