# Confused with & * and [] () with dynamic arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a code in C with these lines included:

```
int i;
int *serie = malloc(sizeof(int)); 

    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        serie=rand(); 
        printf("%d ",&serie[i]);/* *serie */
    }
```

It does work but I want to know why, with malloc I believe I am creating a dynamic array or pointer called serie so far my knowledge is:

```
& returns the address
* returns the content of the adress
```

With fixed arrays you use `[]` and with pointers `()`

By testing `&serie[i]` seems to work but It does not `*serie(i)` or `*serie[i]` and `*serie` I think It does not too.

Can someone explain me these?

If I wanted to print the contents should not I put `*` instead of `&`, I think with dynamic arrays you use `[]` instead of `()` so it should be `*serie[i]` not `&serie[i]`?

Comment: The original code was *serie=rand() still bad but I do not know why I deleted the * from serie, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code, `serie` is a **pointer to an integer**. The line with `malloc()` allocates space for it, such that setting or getting an integer to/from `*serie` will work. The loop seems to incorrectly be setting the return value of `rand()` (an integer) to `serie`. That particular line should look like this, in your current code (but it's not what you want anyway):

```
*serie = rand();
```

Because `rand()` returns an integer, and `serie` alone is a pointer to an integer. However, `*serie` is an integer that you can set to.

In the `printf()`, you're trying to access `serie` as an array, but that won't work because you've only allocated a single element. Well, it will work, but only for element zero.

If you're trying to set and generate 20 random elements (but using a "dynamic" array), you might want something like this:

```
int i;
// note allocating the proper number of elements
int *serie = malloc(sizeof(int) * 20);

// note starting at and going < 20 for 20 elements
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    serie[i] = rand();
    printf("%d ", serie[i]); // *(serie + i) will also work here
}
```

Note that any time you use square brackets to access an element, it's dereferencing it, much like `*` does. So `serie[i]` and `*(serie + i)` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Yes Dan You were right, It was actually like that *serie= rand() check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514049/time-h-works-in-c-not-in-c somehow I deleted but I did not want that I think you are right twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
With fixed arrays you use [] and with pointers ()
```

Incorrect. You can use the same syntax for both pointers and fixed arrays.

To get the value of the i:th element in the array serie you can write either:

```
serie[i]
```

or

```
*(serie + i)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI... Line two declares a pointer to an integer, and allocates the space for an integer.  However, since this is not freed, that memory is leaked.

The allocated memory is not used at all, as `serie` is later reassigned to a random memory location (remember, `serie` is a pointer to an int, not an int itself, so the rand() is assigning a random memory address).

The array syntax dereferences the pointer to a value, as does the asterisk.  `serie` is a pointer to an int.  `*serie` and `serie[0]` are both the VALUE at the location pointed to by `serie`.  `serie[i]` is an integer value at location i, it is no longer a pointer.

`&serie[i]` is printing the address of an integer that is `i` ints away from the random location.  `*serie[i]` tries to dereference the pointer twice, once with the brackets, and again with the asterisk, which is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

*serie is just another name for serie[0].  *(serie + 1) is another name for serie[1].  They both compile to the same machine code.  Use whatever makes your own code most readable.  Array of objects? Use [].  Pointer to a string? Use *.

Answer (score 0):

This looks horribly broken:

1. `serie=rand();` assigns an integer (the return value of `rand()`) to an integer pointer, hardly a sensible or valid thing to do.
2. `&serie[i]` reads random memory, since you overwrote the pointer with the random number.