# Passing variables to a function: scope and when to use & and *?

Tags: c, function, scope

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void test (int a,int *b, int result[], int serie[]);

int main()
{
    int *serie = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int result[20], a,b, i;
    a=0;
    b=0;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        result[i]=i+10;
        serie[i]=rand();
        printf("result is %d \n",result[i]);
    }

    test(a,&b,result,serie);
    printf("value of a inside main %d \n",a);
    printf("value of b inside main %d \n",b);

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("value of result inside main is %d and of serie is %d        \n",result[i],serie[i]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void test(int a, int *b, int result[], int serie[]) {
    int i;
    a=13;
    *b=14;
    printf("value of a inside the function %d \n",a);
    printf("value of b inside the function %d \n",*b);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        result[i]=result[i]*2;
        serie[i]=7;
        printf("value of result inside the function is %d and of serie is %d\n",result[i],serie[i]);
    }
}
```

Basically, all this code does is seeing the scope of the variables, I wrote it to help myself I thought as to change the value of the integer inside `main` with a function (see `int b`) You have to call it with `&b` (`test(a,&b,result,serie);`) and then inside the function `*b`. So I was trying those kind of operations *&** with the arrays but They did not work.

It seems all you have to do It is write the array `void test(... int result[],int serie[])` and to call the function just put the name with no brackets at all: `test(...,result,serie);` am I right?

What if I only want to change the arrays inside the function like with variable `a`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused with & * and \[\] () with dynamic arrays in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522877/confused-with-and-with-dynamic-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. In order to modify arrays, all you  need to do is declare it like:

```
void test(... int result[], int serie[]);
```

or this:

```
void test(... int *result, int *serie);
```

Both the above are equivalent.

Why this is true is that you're passing in a pointer, which gets **passed by value**. This is distinct from the array itself, which is **passed by reference** (via the pointer). So the pointer is copied, and if you tried to actually change the value of result without using `*`, it wouldn't last outside the function. If you want to modify the arrays inside the function without modifying the originals, you have to copy them, either before you pass it in or after.

Comment: I am not sure If I have understood you, my own thoughts which I believe It is what you are saying is that normal variables (not arrays) need a pointer to pass by value but the array themselves are like pointers and are passed by reference so you do not need to create another pointer that points the array right?

Comment: @user1094566: Sort of.  Arrays are not pointers, but in most contexts, an expression of array type will be *replaced* with an expression of pointer type whose value is the address of the first element in the array.  IOW, when you call `test` in `main`, the parameter `result` is converted from a 20-element array of `int` to a pointer to `int`, and its value is the address of `test[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are always passed by reference in C, so passing the address of an array of ints to a function (e.g. `&result` in `main`) is like passing a double pointer (`int**`). The error you received when you tried this was a typing error.

> What if I only want to change the arrays inside the function like with variable a?

I'm not sure what you mean by this question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Dan Fergo understood that, " If you want to modify the arrays inside the function without modifying the originals, you have to copy them, either before you pass it in or after." that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you pass without brackets is because the name of the array defaults to the address of its first entry:

```
  test(a, &b, result, serie);  
// is the same as  
  test(a,&b, &result[0], &serie[0]);
```

To save the original array without modifying it, you have to pass a copy of the array instead of its address.  The easiest way I can think of to do that is to wrap the array in a struct and pass that struct by value.  It will copy the whole array into the local function and allow you to do with it what you will without affecting the original.  There is no way to pass an array by value (that I know of) in C.  Deferencing just returns the first entry of the array - another quirk of the C language.